# Android: Toolbar Tablayout, icons rendering above text

Tags: android, layout, graphics, tabs, android-appcompat

I have a simple Layout in a Dialog with a `AppCompat Toolbar` and `TabLayout` inside. I want my tabs to have icons left of text.

> Here is a layout of the dialog.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            >

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

then I programatically add the tabs.

```
tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab()
                .setTag(SettingsTabTag)
                .setText("Settings")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.scan_tab_settings_black), true);
tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab()
                .setTag(MetadataTabTag)
                .setText("Metadata")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.scan_tab_metadata_black));
```

**But the icon is always rendering above the text and a very small.**

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

1.create a custom tab layout

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAlignment="center"/>
```

2.IN Your activity set the custom tab

```
TextView newTab = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
newTab.setText("tab1"); //tab label txt
newTab.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(your_drawable_icon_here, 0, 0, 0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(tab_index_here_).setCustomView(newTab);
```

[setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) does  the work.

Answer (score 2):

Here are code commonly used to get icon to the left of tab title.

In my case, I have to add a linear layout to center tablayout title. I have also added some space characters to get margin between the icon and the text.

**custom_tab.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Initialization code:**

```
LinearLayout tabLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
TextView tabContent = (TextView) tabLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.tabContent);
tabContent.setText("  "+getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(tabTitles[i]));
tabContent.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(tabIcons[i], 0, 0, 0);
mTabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(tabContent);
```